# Possessive form of "one of [a list]"?

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plural possessive with separate posessions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57142/plural-possessive-with-separate-posessions)

Which of the following is more correct? Or is there another form I'm missing?

> We drove to the movies in one of my **buddy's car**.
>   We drove to the theater in one of my **buddies' cars**.
>   We drove to the theater in one of my **buddies' car**.

I suppose the fundamental question is: does this phrasing suggest "one of [the collection of cars owned by my buddies]" or "the car owned by [one of my buddies]"?

Comment: @MattЭллен Good find; however, the answer to that question is of a completely different form. I'm looking to select the (colloquially) correct sentence of a similar form to the ones I suggested.

Comment: @jtbandes: I see nothing in your question that's not in the original. *Buddy* is pluralised or not primarily depending on whether more than one buddy has a car that *might* have been used. Colloquially, *car* is normally pluralised - largely because no-one wants to get bogged down in the question of whether *"one of"* identifies a specific *buddy*, or a specific *car* (although common, the syntax is inherently ambiguous).

Comment: Also see this one: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52751/does-this-type-of-grammatical-construction-give-an-ambiguous-meaning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean "one of the cars belonging to one buddy":

> We drove to the movies in one of my **buddy's cars**.

If you mean "one of the cars belonging to one of my buddies" or "the one car owned by one of my buddies":

> We drove to the theater in one of my **buddies' cars**.

Answer (score 2):

I think that "We drove to the movies in one of my buddy's car." is *incorrect* because "one of" implies a plural, which is lacking.

Both of the latter two forms are correct. The first means "one of the cars belonging to my buddies", and would be appropriate, for example, if you are talking about buddies who are car collectors. The last means "the car belonging to one of my buddies".

My gut feeling is that in common usage, the last form "one of my buddies' car" would be the best usage, because we usually think of someone driving their car, or having a car, even when they have more than one. [I use "they" rather than "his" in the last sentence following post-modern usage.]

Comment: I chose to say "buddies' cars" because my thinking was that even if only one car is the one being driven, it's likely in this context that one is speaking about more than one possible car, in addition to talking about more than one buddy. If there were only one car in question, it wouldn't make near as much sense to leave the owner ambiguous. I think "one of my buddies' car" is grammatically correct, but it sounds strange, at least to me.

Comment: "One of my buddies' car" sounds correct to me - native American English speaker from Seattle, vintage 1953, expat since 1977. We would have considered "one of my buddies' cars" to be a linguistic marker of a low prestige speaker unless clearly referring to multiple cars. Common US usage today might be as you state though, so I think that your choice is Ok. The language has moved on since my days in the US.